# How can I use 2G voice calls in Nexus 7

Tags: sms, calls, nexus-7, phone-app, 2g

I have bought a Google Nexus 7 3G Tablet.

But, My country and area doesn't allow me to use 3G sims/Wi-Fi.

We have only 2G sims. When I insert the sim, I can connect to the Internet. I can send and receive SMS messages via "Go SMS Pro" application.

But, I am unable to use voice call system which is available in any simple nokia / samsung java supported mobile.

Will my Nexus 7 allow me to send and receive Voice calls in 2G network? Because, to know sim balance we have to call on *XXX# or to know about data usage (Internet MB), we have to dial a number. Also, to call any phone number, we have to dial. So, what can I do to send and receive Calls like any simple mobile phone?

Comment: Possibly related: [Can the Nexus 7 send and receive GSM texts and calls?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32673/can-the-nexus-7-send-and-receive-gsm-texts-and-calls)

Comment: [Nexus 7 3G](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_google_nexus_7_cellular-5091.php) tablets (not the WiFi only model) does have radio to communicate with 2G signals. Could you try after inserting the SIM, please switch over to 'only 2G' or 'only GSM' mode by selecting `Settings`->`More`->`Mobile network settings`->`Use only 2G Networks`. This will make the tablet to work with 2G networks.

Comment: Specifically for the `*xxx#` MMI / USSD codes, see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40616). With a rooted phone and a custom ROM that includes the Telephony app, you should be able to do that. Still no voice calls though, which I believe is due to the "Radio" firmware of the Nexus 7 not supporting that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything. The Nexus 7 3G doesn't support voice calls.